# Xcode: evaluate expression not doing anything

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and just set a breakpoint so I can test evaluating some expressions. The problem is, after I add an expression like this one:

> ```
> [spawnPoint[@"x"] integerValue]
> ```

The result of that expression will say "Enter expression" as if I didn't put anything in there. Why? I've tested that some methods work and others won't. This expression definitely does not error out when it's run in the code. It results in some integer value. Pretty confused...

EDIT: from what I can tell so far, xcode does not allow me to use any class (static/instance) methods at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `p`, or print to get the

```
p [spawnPoint[@"x"] integerValue]
```

If the object you wanted to log was an object, you would do

```
po spawnPoint[@"x"]
```

**Edit**

I was able to get a response from the compile with either of these two

```
p [(NSString*)spawnPoint[@"x"] integerValue]
p [(NSString*)[spawnPoint objectForKey:@"x"] integerValue]
```

Comment: thx, I've also tried the debugger but that leads to '[no Objective-C description available]'

Comment: Updated answer, try p instead of po

Comment: well i have no idea what p does but it leads to not recognizing the integerValue method

Comment: "p" is short for print, "po" is short for print object.